# Liferay API: Get Roles via Permissions

Tags: java, api, jsf, liferay

At the moment I'm trying to create an overview where I list all the Layouts and Portlets and Roles (Permissions) that are activated for every of them.

I think I'm pretty near to the solution already but the last bit is missing.

I already got all kind of information I need. I got form Layout --> to Resource --> to Permission. But now I don't know how to get from the Permissions (or permissionId) to the actual Roles via the Liferay API.

what I have: Layout, Resource, Permission
what I need: Roles

Using Liferay 5.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I finally found it out myself. All I'm doing now is:

```
List<Layout> tempPages = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayouts( 0, LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutsCount() );
List<Role> allAvailRoles = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRoles( 0, RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRolesCount() );
for ( Layout page : tempPages )
{
    List<Role> mappedRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    for ( Role role : allAvailRoles )
    {
        boolean hasRolePermission = PermissionLocalServiceUtil.hasRolePermission( role.getRoleId(),
                                                                                  page.getCompanyId(),
                                                                                  Layout.class.getName(),
                                                                                  ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,
                                                                                  String.valueOf( page.getPrimaryKey() ),
                                                                                  "VIEW" );
        if ( hasRolePermission )
        {
           mappedRoles.add( role );
        }
     }
     pages.add( new LayoutRoleModel( page, mappedRoles ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use RoleLocalServiceUtil.
companyId you can get over the Liferay user by calling user.getCompanyId. and user you can retrieve by this way: user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserById(id);

```
private static Role getLiferayRole(String roleName, long companyId) {
    Role role = null;
    try {
        role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, roleName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    } 
    return role;
}
```